# primefaces dialog as a tooltip like facebook show people details

Tags: primefaces

I want to show the details of a person with a dialog as shown on Facebook when the mouse is placed on a person's name.

I am using dialog framework in `primefaces`.
The dialog should display data that must be loaded when the mouse is placed on the person.

The problem is the dialog position:

```
<p:dataTable filterDelay="700"  reflow="true"   emptyMessage="No se encontraron elementos"  widgetVar="tblist"  
   id="dataTableList" var="item"  paginator="true"  paginatorPosition="bottom"
   rows="10" rowKey="#{item.idPersona}" value="#{listadoPersonasMB.listPersonas}" filteredValue="#{listadoPersonasMB.filterlistPersonas}">
   <f:facet name="header">
      Resultado de la búsqueda #{listadoPersonasMB.cantPerFilter}
   </f:facet>
   <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="handleLoadStart();"/>
   <p:column  style="width: 50px">
      <p:graphicImage  style="border-radius: 50%"  alt="image" id="fotoPer"  value="#{listadoPersonasMB.fotoPersonaTabla}" cache="false" width="100%">
         <f:param name="personId" value="#{item.idPersona}" />
      </p:graphicImage>
   </p:column>
   <p:column width="100%"  headerText="Nombre y apellidos" sortBy="#{item.nombre}" style="text-align: left" filterBy="#{item.nombre} #{item.nombre2} #{item.apellidos} #{item.apellidos2}" filterMatchMode="contains">
      <p:commandLink ajax="false" id="pict" action="#{mBDetallesPersona.detallesPersona(item.idPersona)}" onmouseover="showPersonDetail();">
         <h:outputText value="#{item.nombre} #{item.nombre2} #{item.apellidos} #{item.apellidos2}"/>
      </p:commandLink>
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:remoteCommand id="rcomperson" name="showPersonDetail" process="@this" 
   actionListener="#{listadoPersonasMB.showPersonDetail}"
   update=":form2:perDeta" oncomplete="PF('carOP').show('#{component.clientId}')"
   />
<p:overlayPanel widgetVar="carOP" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
   <p:outputPanel id="perDeta">
      <ui:include src="perDialog.xhtml" />
   </p:outputPanel>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: Why a dialog? ?Why not an overlay? See the PrimeFaces showcase

Comment: I'm trying now, but I should load the data before showing it in overlaypanel.

Comment: Yes, so? Don't see the problem...

Comment: It shows me the overlaypanle below the table, not like in the showcase, near the button, I'm using onmouseover event to launch the remotecommand which loads the data from the datelles panel.

Comment: Read the documentation....

Comment: The problem is to pass the pocision from the commanlink to the remotecommmand to the overlaypanel...

Comment: why do you need to pass it like that?

Comment: because I need to show overlaypanel just onmouseover commanlink, onmouseover call remotecommand and remote comand call overlaypanel... please see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution with overlayPanel, remoteCommand and some javascript code

> xhtml

```
          <p:dataTable filterDelay="700"  reflow="true"   emptyMessage="No se encontraron elementos"  widgetVar="tblist"  
                                             id="dataTableList" var="item"  paginator="true"  paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                             rows="10" rowKey="#{item.idPersona}" value="#{listadoPersonasMB.listPersonas}" filteredValue="#{listadoPersonasMB.filterlistPersonas}"> 
                                    <f:facet name="header">
                                        Resultado de la búsqueda #{listadoPersonasMB.cantPerFilter}
                                    </f:facet>                                        
                                    <p:column  style="width: 50px">   
                                        <p:graphicImage  style="border-radius: 50%"  alt="image" id="fotoPer"  value="#{listadoPersonasMB.fotoPersonaTabla}" cache="false" width="100%">
                                            <f:param name="personId" value="#{item.idPersona}" />                           
                                        </p:graphicImage>

                                    </p:column> 

                                    <p:column width="100%"  headerText="Nombre y apellidos" sortBy="#{item.nombre}" style="text-align: left" filterBy="#{item.nombre} #{item.nombre2} #{item.apellidos} #{item.apellidos2}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                                        <p:commandLink ajax="false"  action="#{mBDetallesPersona.detallesPersona(item.idPersona)}" onmouseover="loadPersonDetalles('#{component.clientId}', #{item.idPersona});">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{item.nombre} #{item.nombre2} #{item.apellidos} #{item.apellidos2}"/>
                                        </p:commandLink>

                                    </p:column>   

                                    <p:column headerText="Edad" sortBy="#{item.calculaEdad()}" style="text-align: right; width: 60px"  sortFunction="#{utilMB.ordenarEnteros}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{item.calculaEdad()}"/>
                                    </p:column>    
                                    <p:column filterBy="#{item.miembro eq true ? 'Sí' : 'No'}" headerText="Membresía"  filterMatchMode="contains" style="width: 220px">

                                        <h:outputText value="#{item.miembro eq true ? 'Sí' : 'No'}" />
                                        <span> <p:commandButton rendered="#{mBLogin.siTieneFuncion('AdminPersonas')}"  icon="fa fa-refresh Fs16 white" title="Cambiar" 
                                                                actionListener="#{listadoPersonasMB.selectToSetMember(item)}" oncomplete="PF('newDialog').show()"/>   </span>
                                    </p:column>

                                    <p:column   style="text-align: center; width: 40px" rendered="#{mBLogin.siTieneFuncion('AdminPersonas')}">  
                                        <p:commandButton  icon="fa fa-pencil Fs16 white" title="Modificar" 
                                                          action="#{listadoPersonasMB.cargaPersonaModi(item.idPersona)}"/>                                        
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column   style="text-align: center; width: 40px" rendered="#{mBLogin.siTieneFuncion('AdminPersonas')}">  
                                        <p:commandButton  icon="fa fa-trash Fs16 white" title="Dar Baja" 
                                                          action="#{mBDeletePersona.detallesPersona(item.idPersona)}"/>                                        
                                    </p:column>
                                </p:dataTable>   

                                <p:remoteCommand  name="showPersonDetail" process="@this" 
                                                  actionListener="#{listadoPersonasMB.showPersonDetail}"
                                                  update=":form2:perDeta"  oncomplete="loadPanel();"/> 

                                <p:overlayPanel widgetVar="carOP" my="right bottom" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade"
                                                dismissable="true" hideEvent="onmouseout"
                                                dynamic="true" 
                                                >
                                    <p:outputPanel id="perDeta">                                                        
                                        <ui:include src="perDialog.xhtml" />
                                    </p:outputPanel>                                               
                                </p:overlayPanel>
```

> javascript code, send param to remoteCommand

```
 <h:outputScript id="waypointScript" target="body">  

        var idcom = 0;

        function loadPersonDetalles(idC, idPer) {                     
         showPersonDetail([{name:'x', value:idPer}, {name:'y', value:20}]);  
         idcom = idC;
        }

        function loadPanel() {                               
         PF('carOP').show(idcom);
        }

    </h:outputScript>
```

> backingbean

```
 public void showPersonDetail() {
    try {

        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        this.idPerSeledtToDialog = Integer.valueOf(params.get("x"));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, "Error: filterListener() " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```